# I can not save List<MyEntity> in parent entity with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PP_CRM")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id", "ppConfig"})
public class PricePlanCrm {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter private String rkId;
    @Getter @Setter private String name;
    @Getter @Setter private String priceplantype;
    @Getter @Setter private String enabled;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PP_CONFIG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    @Getter @Setter private PricePlanConfig ppConfig;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PP_CONFIG")
public class PricePlanConfig {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter private String Name;
    @Getter @Setter private String wfaId;
    @Getter @Setter private Integer status;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ppConfig", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter @Setter private List<PricePlanCrm> ppCrm;
}
```

I want save `PricePlanConfig`  with List of `PricePlanCrm` and all saved but `PP_CONFIG_ID` column has not `ID` of `PricePlanConfig`.

This id my method for save

```
public void savePricePlanConfig(){
        PricePlanConfig pricePlanConfig = new PricePlanConfig();
        pricePlanConfig.setName(pricePlanConfigName);
        pricePlanConfig.setWfaId(workFlowId);
        int status = Boolean.parseBoolean(isActive) ? 1 : 0;
        pricePlanConfig.setStatus(status);
        List<PricePlanCrm> pricePlansClear = getPricePlansClear();
        pricePlanConfig.setPpCrm(pricePlansClear);
        PricePlanConfigDaoImpl.me().persist(pricePlanConfig);
        clearForm();
    }
```

Aftere save I have two tables but in `PP_CRM` table I have `PP_CONFIG_ID` column where all values is `EMPTY`.

**EDIT**

When I use `nullable = false` in line

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PP_CONFIG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
```

I have error

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : crm.entity.PricePlanCrm.ppConfig
```

If I add this to my save method

```
for (PricePlanCrm pricePlanCrm : pricePlansClear) {
            pricePlanCrm.setPpConfig(pricePlanConfig);
        }
```

all `ID` save normal but I think it is bad practic and hibernate must save this automaticly. I think? hibernate tried save `PricePlanCrm`  entyty before saved `PricePlanConfig`  and tried set `PricePlanConfig` to `PricePlanCrm` but `PricePlanConfig` as yet not saved and is null. I think hibernate must save PricePlanConfig (It is Parent) before PricePlanCrm(child) but this is not true

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: No all-clear. But when I add nullable = false I get exception

Answer (score 0):

in `PricePlanCrm` you have to mention what is your `targetEntity`

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PricePlanConfig .class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PP_CONFIG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    @Getter @Setter private PricePlanConfig ppConfig;
```

in `PricePlanConfig` try to use `targetEntity`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ppConfig",targetEntity = PricePlanCrm.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter @Setter private List<PricePlanCrm> ppCrm;
```

Comment: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : crm.entity.PricePlanCrm.ppConfig

Comment: can you post full stack?

Comment: can you try by place `optional=true` in both sides?